# Excel VBA code to compare two tables and highlight mismatches

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to write a code which compares the values in two same-sized tables and highlight the values that does not match. The code that I came up with only seems to be highlighting the last cell of the range. I think I am overlooking something very simple over here. Any help to sort this out would be much appreciated. I am putting down the code below.

```
Sub Compare_Table()

Dim oldTable As Range, newTable As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
Set oldTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select old values", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
Set newTable = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select new values", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

i = oldTable.Rows.Count
j = oldTable.Columns.Count


For m = 1 To i
    For n = 1 To j
        If oldTable.Cells(i, j) = newTable.Cells(i, j) Then
            newTable.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
            newTable.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

    Next n
Next m

End Sub
```

Comment: It's much more efficient using conditional formatting, be it directly in Excel or from a VBA module. In this latter case there's a quite recente post nicely answered by Jeeped that would get you in the right path

Comment: @user3598756: That's not fully correct. Depending on the amount of data it might be required to do the highlighting only once in a while and save memory by having the highlighting static. For smaller data areas you are right though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following change in your for loop:

```
For m = 1 To i
    For n = 1 To j
        If oldTable.Cells(m, n) = newTable.Cells(m, n) Then
            newTable.Cells(m, n).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
            newTable.Cells(m, n).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

    Next n
Next m
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a million Mrig! I feel incredibly stupid now!

Comment: Glad I could help.